# How to toggle LED

Tags: embedded

How to toggle LED with push button. I wrote program. There is problem in Program. This program fail if i held the button down continuously  then LED turn ON/OFF  continuously. How to solve problem ?

```
  #include<REGX51.h>

  #define led_off         0
  #define switch_pressed  0

  sbit  Switch = P1^2;                    /*set bit P1^2 to Switch*/

  sbit led = P1^0;                       /*set bit P1^0 to LED*/


  void debounce (unsigned long wait)     /* Debounce function */
  {
       unsigned int i;
       for (i = 0; i < wait;  i++);
  }

  void main (void)
  {
     led = led_off;

  while (1)
  {
      if (Switch ==  switch_pressed)

        {
            led = ~led;
            debounce (40000);
        }

  }
}
```

Comment: `led = ~led;` Because this line toggles the LED continuously? The program does what you tell it to do. Also, your "debounce" function is nonsense.

Comment: A separate issue to your qiestion is your implementation of `debounce()`.  You should at least declare the loop-counter `i` `volatile`.  Stylistically, despite its name, it is not really a debounce but simply a delay used to debounce, the debounce function is implemented in `main()` _using_ this delay.  So for example if elsewhere you needed a delay, would you write a function that does exactly this but with a different name? That would be silly.  You should name functions for what they do, not what they are used for.

Comment: @Lundin - Untrue; a delay or other ignoring of the input after detecting a change can in fact be a perfectly valid method of debouncing.  However one does need to be careful that a loop without any side effects doesn't get optimized out.

Comment: @ChrisStratton It is nonsense for the following reasons: 1) You debounce, read the switch, then take action. You don't read the switch, take action, debounce. This code will trigger on everything from signal bounces, to EMI, to a valid switch action. Debouncing in its simplest form reads the switch, waits, then reads the switch again. This code does not do that. 2) It will get optimized away by the compiler since the loop iterator is not volatile. 3) It burns away CPU and current consumption in a busy-loop, even though the MCU has both on-chip hardware timers and sleep modes available.

Comment: "You don't read the switch, take action, debounce." **Actually, you classically do exactly that**  The simplest form of debouncing is to just *ignore* the input for some time after accepting it.  In ordinary cases this works quite well because what is typically being combated is not initial false actuation, but rather false *re-actuation*.  What you are speaking of is a type of filtering that is much less often employed - generally only in environments with a lot of mechanical vibration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are toggling the button so long as the button is pressed. when you need to toggle it *only* when the button changes from *not pressed* to *pressed*:

```
#include<REGX51.h>

#define BTN_UP  1
#define BTN_DN  0
#define DEBOUNCE_DELAY 40000

sbit Switch = P1^2 ;  
sbit led = P1^0 ;

void delay( unsigned long wait ) 
{
     for( volatile unsigned long i = 0 ; 
          i < wait;  
          i++ )
     { /* do nothing */ } 
}

int main( void )
{
    int prev_button_state = Switch ;
    led = 0 ;

    for(;;)
    {
        // Read current Switch state
        int button_state = Switch ;

        // If BTN_DN event...
        if( button_state != prev_button_state && 
            button_state == BTN_DN )
        {
            led = ~led;
            delay( DEBOUNCE_DELAY ) ;
        }

        prev_button_state = button_state ;
    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: When I press button, led should be turn on and if i press button again led should be turn off. this process should be repeat. my program does this things but when I held the button down continuously. led continuously turn on and turn off , that I don't want to do. how to solve this problem

Comment: @Parth786 : What is it in this answer that does not solve that exact problem?  I restricted my answer to only a fragment that directly answered your question to avoid having to address other unrelated issues with your code.  I have updated the code fragment so that it is a more complete implementation based on your original framework.

Comment: I have compiled that code with design but code not working. it does not toggle led when button press

Comment: So debug it.  I do not have the benefit of your platform to test it on.